# How to apply Exception Globally for Unhanded exceptions in C#(App is combination of WPF,Winforms and Class Library Project)

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

We have a Windows desktop application which is basically done using WPF(Main) and winforms one small part and mainly class library which is doing more business process and services.
We are getting unhandled exception somewhere in the application. We are trying to catch the exception using DispatcherUnhandledException but no use of that.

Application XAML code.

```
 <Application x:Class="MyApp.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
         Startup="Application_Startup"
         DispatcherUnhandledException ="AppDispatcherUnhandledException">
  <Application.Resources>
  </Application.Resources>
  </Application>


private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Global exception handling  
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDispatcherUnhandledException);
    }

    void AppDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            //#if DEBUG   // In debug mode do not custom-handle the exception, let Visual Studio handle it

            e.Handled = false;

            //#else

            ShowUnhandledException(e);    

           // #endif
        }
    }
    void ShowUnhandledException(DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;      
    LogHelper.LogEntry(LogEntryModel.Create(this).Fatal(e.Exception.StackTrace));
    }
```

I can see in my log files last log was written related to the Class Library Services class.
So how to catch that particualr exception.

PS: Here my question is how to catch the unhandle the exception if there are multiple things such as WPF,Winforms and Class Library project used.

Comment: I recommend you rethink your exception handling startegy. You should not have to rely on a catch all block somewhere in your application.

Comment: @Sefe This if for finding the exception and correcting it, Once if we settle down with this then we can proceed thinking of better way. Anyway Thanks for that comment.

Comment: https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/JexusManager/Program.cs see SetUpRollbar method.

Comment: If you want to find the exception, you can set visual studio to break on all exceptions thrown.